# Usar la respuesta de una peticion POST para usarla en otra funcion

Tags: reactjs, react-axios

estoy tratando de enviar una notificación a firebase y necesito enviar el Id de un pedido, lo que pasa es que el Id no existe porque es en la creación del nuevo pedido. Cuando hago el post usando axios he conseguido capturar la respuesta del dato que quiero de la siguiente forma.

```
authAxios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_URL, body)

    .then(response => 

       console.log("respuesta del post " + response.data.id))//este es el ID

          .catch(error  =>  {

             console.log(error);

    })
```

en otro componente tengo la siguiente función que es para crear el pedido que llamará a la funcion que  hará la peticion POST.

```
  function createOrder () {


    const body = {

      title: title,
      description: description,
      units: units,
      price: price,
    

    } 

  
    requestPostNew(body);
    showConfirmationMessage();// mensaje que me dice si me quiero quedar en la misma 
                                // pagina o salir

    setStatusNotification(true);//se activa el boton de notificar cuando se haya guardado 
                                  //el pedido. Cuando se haya hecho el POST
    
      console.log(body);

    

  }
```

Y finalmente la funcion que envia al backend los datos para la notificacion

```
 function sendNotification() {

      if(statusNotification === true){
          const data = {
          
             id: //aqui deberia el ID que intento capturar de la respuesta recibida en el 
                  //POST
            title: title,
            description: description,
            units: units,
            price: price,
            topic:process.env.REACT_APP_URL_ORDER
            
          }

       requestSendNotification(data);
```

He probado usando haciendo un get y luego recorriendo los pedidos y seleccionar el numero id pedido mayor asi funciona, el problema llega cuando se borra un pedido por ejemplo 100 y luego me regresa como id mas alto el 99, pero es que el siguiente no sería el 100 tendria que ser el 101, por lo que en base de datos deberia pasar del 99 al 101. Por eso pregunto como recoger los datos de la respuesta del post porque ahi si sale el id creado correctamente. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Hola he resuelto el problema de la siguiente forma por si le puede ser de ayuda a la comunidad. Lo pondré por orden de código tal cual planteé la pregunta.

```
//Fuera del metodo post declaré una variable
var idOrder;


//En el then le di el valor a la variable con el response que trae el id
authAxios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_URL, body)

    .then(response => {idOrder = response.data.id})) 

          .catch(error  =>  {

             console.log(error);

    })

//defino una constante que va a retornar el valor de idOrder
export const newOrderId = () => {
    return idOrder;

}
```

Exporté la constante newOrderId y en la función que envia los datos al backend para la notificación queda asi:

```
function sendNotification() {

     const id = newOrderId()//la constante que trae el Id del pedido

      if(statusNotification === true){
          const data = {
          
             id:  id, 
            title: title,
            description: description,
            units: units,
            price: price,
            topic:process.env.REACT_APP_URL_ORDER
            
          }

       requestSendNotification(data);
```

Espero que les sirva de ayuda un saludo.